# CakePHP, importing one controller inside another controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, lazy-loading

I need to use a controller functions inside my another controller.
But I don't want to make

```
$Myother = new MyotherController();
```

every time I use a method from that controller.
How can I initialize a controller so I won't make a "new" in every method ?

I found [this](http://www.codeboss.in/web-funda/2009/05/18/how-to-import-a-controller-in-cakephp/), It writes like this:

```
App::import('Controller', 'Pages');
class UsersController extends AppController {
  var $Pages;
  function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Pages =& new PagesController; /*Loads the class*/
    $this->Pages->constructClasses(); /*Loads the model associations, components, etc. of the    Pages controller*/
  }
  function index() {
    $this->Pages->index();
  }
}
```

Is this the proper way, or is there a better way ?

Comment: Hmmm.  Perhaps a refactor of the code is required.  Maybe move the **shared** code into a helper, or move it into a `Model` if that makes sense.

Comment: My codes are mostly controller type codes, rather than view or model codes. So I'm planning to create another controller or component. I ask this to use a new controller inside a controller.

Comment: Using a controller inside another one breaks the MVC structure. I would recommend to use components or models.

Comment: Dont. Cake is designed around 1 request = 1 controller. Either stop using Cake or do things properly. The fact that you are needing to do this shows a fundamental flaw in your code that should be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think really the only way to go is to switch to using some components. Initializing new controllers with their components / helpers / models, will cause much more over head, which might not be worth the trade off. Let alone,  It'll promote bad design.

My advice, is to go with components.

You can always use requestAction() if you need just the result of an action in another controller. However, even CakePHP say people should be careful with it.

"If used without caching requestAction can lead to poor performance. It is rarely appropriate to use in a controller or model."

Answer (score 2):

You should try adding these common methods to your `AppController`, since all controllers extend `AppController` it's a great place to stick common controller functionality.

That being said, if you're loading all the models and associations of one controller into another, then you might be better off moving the associated code into the appropriate model instead.

Comment: That was my beginning. I put all common functions inside AppController. But it became too big too maintain. Nearly 130 kilobytes. So I need to extract some functions into another controller or components.

Comment: @trante The best solution would probably involve looking at all these methods and seeing how they can be separated into logical groups. Components might be the answer, but if these methods do a lot of operations on models (like doing finds, etc), then you should really consider moving that code into the model itself. Let the model deal with your data, your controllers should only control the request/response.